# How to set up an NFS server on Ubuntu

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, osx-snow-leopard, nfs

I'm trying to set up an NFS server on my Ubuntu server to be accessed from my Mac OS X 10.6.4 desktop. I started on the Ubuntu side by following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo) (the quick start). When I finally try to access the NFS share on the Mac I get this:

```
[/Network] cd fileserver 
cd:cd:1: permission denied: fileserver
```

### I finally got this working. I'll outline how below.

#### Server Setup (Ubuntu 10.10)

**/etc/exports**

```
/export                 *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
/export/fileserver      *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
/export/fileserver2     *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

**/etc/fstab**

```
/fileserver/a/root   /export/fileserver  none   bind          0       0
/fileserver/b/root   /export/fileserver2 none   bind          0       0
```

#### Client Setup (Mac OS X 10.6.7)

The key problem was that `id -u tsigo` on the server was 1000, and on Mac it was 501. In order to change this I followed [this guide](http://www.inteller.net/notes/change-user-id-on-snow-leopard) which -- be warned -- was fraught with potential disaster; follow directions closely. If I were doing it again I would change my ID on the server instead.

After changing my user ID and rebooting, it was mostly straight forward.

Open Disk Utility, go to File > NFS Mounts and add a new entry.

NFS URL: `nfs://gluttony/export/fileserver`
Mount location: `/Network/fileserver`
Advanced mount params: `-i,-s,-P`

Comment: What are the permissions?

Comment: Added to the bottom of the question.

Comment: ... and your uid on the Mac equals to one that is in Ubuntu?

Comment: It does not. Mac is 501, Ubuntu is 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct you need the same `uid`'s on client and server. Though you can achieve this without 'changing' the owners of the files on client or server. If you use `anonuid` and `all_squash` in your export file you can map any `uid` you would like to the client that is accessing the share.

Example exports file:

```
/home/brian   *(rw,async,no_subtree_check,insecure,anonuid=1000,all_squash)
```

Given that `/home/brian` permissions are `drwxr-xr-x 24 1000 1000` you'll have full access.
Hope this helps.

P.S. this should apply to `anongid` also but for some strange reason it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have same uid between the two computers. If you Mac user has an uid 501 and Ubuntu 1000, then with your current permissions you will correctly get "Permission denied". See, you only have full access for user *tsigo* and everyone else has only read access to directories.

You either need to make the uid match or grant more privileges to group and/or others. A *read* permission is not enough to let anyone enter a directory, you need grant also *+x*.

Comment: I did `chmod -R a+rx /fileserver` on the server and it's still a no-go.